# Calculating percentage changes (pandas)

Tags: pandas

I'm trying to get the % of fruit choice appearing on a specific day/month, like what's shown in the example.

I'm able to get total mean on the entire df with the following line. However, I'd like to view the changes in percentage through the days/months.

```
df['apple%'] = df['fruit'].eq(apple).groupby(df['name']).transform('mean')

df['orange%'] = df['fruit'].eq(orange).groupby(df['name']).transform('mean')
```

Original df:

```
date    name    fruit   
1-Jan   john    apple       
1-Feb   john    orange  
1-Mar   john    apple   
1-Apr   john    apple   
1-May   john    orange  
1-Jun   john    apple   
1-Jul   john    apple
```

What i hope to get:

```
date    name    fruit    apple%     orange%
1-Jan   john    apple    100%   
1-Feb   john    orange   50%        50%
1-Mar   john    apple    67%        33%
1-Apr   john    apple    75%        25%
1-May   john    orange   60%        40%
1-Jun   john    apple    67%        33%
1-Jul   john    apple    71%        29%
```

i've added the df as suggested. 
Many thanks

```py
data = {'date':['1-Jan', '1-Feb', '1-Mar', '1-Apr', '1-May', '1-Jun', '1-July'], 'name':['john', 'john', 'john', 'john', 'john', 'john', 'john'], 
 'fruit':['apple', 'orange', 'apple', 'apple', 'orange', 'apple', 'apple']} 

df = pd.DataFrame(data) 

print(df)
```

Comment: It would be good if you provide the code to generate the `original df` easily so developers can focus on finding a solution to you problem and not waste time on generating the `original df`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
df['values']=(df.groupby(['fruit','name']).cumcount()+1)/(df.groupby('name')['fruit'].cumcount()+1)
df2=df.pivot_table(index=df.index,columns='fruit',values='values').rename_axis(columns=None)
df2=df2.apply(lambda x: x.fillna(1-df2.sum(axis=1)) )*100
new_df=pd.concat([df.drop('values',axis=1),df2],axis=1)
print(new_df)
```

---

**Output**

```
    date  name   fruit       apple     orange
0  1-Jan  john   apple  100.000000   0.000000
1  1-Feb  john  orange   50.000000  50.000000
2  1-Mar  john   apple   66.666667  33.333333
3  1-Apr  john   apple   75.000000  25.000000
4  1-May  john  orange   60.000000  40.000000
5  1-Jun  john   apple   66.666667  33.333333
6  1-Jul  john   apple   71.428571  28.571429
```

---

Comment: Hi ansev, thank you for the help. What should be changed in the line when i have more than two types of fruits (apple, orange, banana, etc) and names (john, pete, jane).

Comment: data = {'date':['1-Jan', '1-Feb', '1-Mar', '1-Apr', '1-May', '1-Jun', '1-July', '1-Aug', '1-Sep'], 'name':['pete', 'john', 'john', 'john', 'john', 'john', 'pete', 'john', 'jane'], 'fruit':['apple', 'banana', 'orange', 'apple', 'banana', 'orange', 'apple', 'apple', 'banana']}